# What is the use of const in const -> decltype(t+u)?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, decltype

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

struct Polly
{
    template<typename T,typename U>
    auto operator()(T t,U u) const -> decltype(t+u)
    {
        return t+u;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto polly=std::bind(Polly(),std::placeholders::_1,"confunsing");

    std::cout<<polly(4)<<polly(std::string(" this is "))<<std::endl;
}
```

Now I don`t understand the use of const here:  const -> decltype(t+u). I am using decltype to be able to return multiples types of data.

Comment: the `const` makes the operator a `const` function. (does not modify `this`)

Comment: Okay guys sorry for duplicating this question! And thanks for the help!